# Chaining observables sequentially

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

In Angular I want to return an object in route `resolve` field that contains a list and for each item of the list I want to execute an additional request that would modify it. It looks something like this:

```
this.employeesService.getEmployees(route.parent.params['department'])
  .map(employeesResponse => {
    employeesResponse.employees.map(employee => 
      employee.status = this.employeesService.checkStatus(route.parent.params['department'], employee))
  })
```

`getEmployees` returns a wrapper response object:

```
{
  operationId: 1
  employees: [],
}
```

`checkStatus` returns a string which is an employee status.

I know this does not work but I tried doing this in many different ways and have no idea how it can be accomplished. I know how to do this when a list is returned from the first request but I must preserve this wrapper object.

What is the best way to do this with Rx? I'm quite new to the reactive programming concept.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the getEmployees response object but with each employee's status added. Your `employees.map` is adding the status to each employee (should be forEach though). Why not just `return employeesResponse` in your rxjs map method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.mergeMap()` with a concurrency argument to have multiple items be modified in the same time. This is not order preserving so might be an issue.

If ordering is required you can use `.concatMap()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can easily achieve the result where a list (a modified one) is returned with the following code:

```
this.employeesService.getEmployees(route.parent.params['department'])
  .mergeMap((employeesResponse: EmployeesResponse) => employeesResponse.employees)
  .mergeMap((employee: Employee) => this.checkEmployee(route.parent.params['department'], employee)
  .map(statusResponse => {
    employee.status = statusResponse.status;
    return employee
  })
```

);

However, I don't want that list. I want it to be wrapped within the `EmployeeResponse`. This is the place where I have a problem, not which operator to use.

Comment: `mergeMap` breaks down the stream from array to elements so you can map each item, then I think `toArray` will bring them back together again - would need to mock up a working example to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

As per your answer, but taking the status check mapping inside the mergeMap and rebuilding the list with `toArray`.

The only thing lost is `operationId`. Does that matter?

```js
// Mock services
const routeParamsDept = 'Sales';
const employeesService = {
  getEmployees: (department) => {
    return Rx.Observable.of({
      operationId: 1,
      employees: [
        {name: 'Joe', status: 'Perm', dept: 'Sales'},
        {name: 'Jane', status: 'Temp', dept: 'Sales'}
      ]
    });
  } 
}
const checkEmployee = (department, employee) => Rx.Observable.of({status: 'Perm'})

const fetchedAndChecked = employeesService.getEmployees(routeParamsDept)
  .mergeMap(employeesResponse => employeesResponse.employees)
  .mergeMap(employee => {
    return checkEmployee(routeParamsDept, employee)
      .map(statusResponse => {
        employee.status = statusResponse.status;
        return employee
      })
  })
  .toArray()

fetchedAndChecked.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```